# Iterate through XML node and update an element in C# without Linq

Tags: c#, xml

I am stuck in a situation where I have to update one node element based on the condition where two other element in that node should exist than only it should update the element.
For ex: I have this XML
[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVtHR.jpg)

And I want to update ItemId in detail node if EventID and SubEventId in same node are 10154 and 12 respectively.

Please suggest, i am new to DOM and C#.

Comment: Why do you need to solve the problem **without** LINQ?

Comment: There is other code which is already written using Xpath and XMLdoucment classes, so I am also looking from there itself. Thanks.